# How to create a procedure to insert which returns the inserted row

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, delimiter

Here is my current SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addBlog(@title VARCHAR(255), @body VARCHAR(255), OUT @uuid INT) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO blogs b (b.title, b.detail) VALUES (@title, @body);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @uuid;
    SELECT @uuid;
END
```

Which is throwing this error (directly from SQL export):

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@title VARCHAR(255), @body VARCHAR(255), OUT @uuid INT) BEGIN
>       INSERT INTO blog' at line 1

My Database has an `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` on `uuid INT (255)` which I want to return using this procedure. Any help would be great.

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `blogs` (
  `uuid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `detail` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `blogs`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`);

ALTER TABLE `blogs`
  MODIFY `uuid` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

ALTER TABLE `blogs`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `blogs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` 
(`uuid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

UPDATED SQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addBlog(
    IN in_title VARCHAR(255),
    IN in_body VARCHAR(255), 
    IN in_user INT(255),
    OUT out_uuid INT
) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `blogs` (`title`, `detail`, `user_id`) VALUES (in_title, in_body, in_user);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO out_uuid;
    SELECT out_uuid;
END;
```

Comment: Your question says you want to return the inserted row. This returns the `uuid` of that row. Also, you can make your last SELECT say this `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS out_uuid;` and get the  same result as your last two SELECTs. Also, `int(255)` isn't a thing. Use `INT` for a 32-bit value and `BIGINT` for a 64-bit value.

Comment: Apologies, you can update the question title to say row ID if its more applicable, I dint know how to word it @O.Jones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing parameter type definition such as `IN`, `OUT` etc. Also, I don't think you need to use `@`, in parameter definition.

Also, I like to ensure that name of the variables/parameters in a Stored Procedure / Trigger etc, are different from any of the table/column name(s) used in them.

Also, if you haven't done it already, you need to redefine Delimiter to something else (like, `$$`) other than `;`; and redefine it back to `;` at the end.

```
DELIMITER $$ -- define the delimiter

CREATE PROCEDURE addBlog(IN title_in VARCHAR(255), -- added suffix "in" to param name
                         IN body_in VARCHAR(255), 
                         OUT uuid_out INT) BEGIN
...... 

END $$ -- end of stored procedure
DELIMITER ; -- redefine delimiter back to ;
```

Comment: Still getting the error  at `CREATE PROCEDURE addBlog(
    IN in_title VARCHAR(255),
 IN in_body VARCHAR(255), 
    IN in_user INT(255),
 OUT out_uuid INT
) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO blogs (title, detail, user_id) VALUES (in_title, in_body, in_user)` - I updated it to include the `in_user` since I think it cannot be NULL

Comment: `1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7` - I'll update question to show the newest SQL

Comment: Your updated solution worked! I'll have to google `DELMITER` I have no clue what that is and how it made it work, thank you so much!

Comment: @Jaquarh it is required so that MySQL/Mariadb parser will not stop at `;` and read/compile the complete stored procedure definition at once.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is a weird mish-mash from multiple databases.  I think you want:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addBlog (
    in_title VARCHAR(255),
    in_body VARCHAR(255),
    OUT out_uuid INT
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO blogs (title, detail)
        VALUES (in_title, in_body);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO out_uuid;
    -- SELECT out_uuid;
END;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=781ec398bcee993650ad86e47e3a964a) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Returns this error doing this :( 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7

Comment: Is it because I'm not declaring who the user is who created the blog? I wanted to do this later on, maybe I have to do it inside that query?

Comment: I tried adding `in_user INT(255)` but `INSERT INTO blogs (title, detail, user_id) VALUES (in_title, in_body, in_user);` is still throwing the error

Comment: @Jaquarh . . . Contrary to expectations, I tested the code as shown in the link.

Comment: Not too sure why, but I had to add `DELIMITER $$` like shown in the other answer, I have no clue why this didn't work if it works in the DB fiddle :/ I'll upvote for others tho! Thanks so much

Comment: Perhaps you don't even want or need the final `SELECT out_uuid;`